# How to make sure QProcess external launched App stays on top

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess

I have a menu that, when toggled, starts a QProcess that lauches an external app. 
How to make sure that the launched upp stays on top since I can't use the QT Window flag?

Comment: If the process is stand-alone, and thus interacts with the window manager on its own, Qt can do very little for you. I suggest looking into your window manager.

Comment: Can you patch the code of that external process?

Comment: @dvvrd it's just any stand alone app, could be firefox or whatever. I'm just trying to make it stick always on top of the application that has the menu to launch it.

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind Since I can't identify the process, I wanted something that I can add as argument when i start the process, do you thik this is possible ?

Comment: @alkah depends on the window manager. I suggest looking for some documentation about your window manager.